# R packages cem and MatchIt: Different imbalance measure

Tags: r, matching

I am running coarsened exact matching (CEM) via the package MatchIt as a pre-processing step and want to use the matched data in further analyses. As a test, I ran CEM using the package cem, and noticed that the imbalance measure differed from the one via the MatchIt package.
For example, using the LaLonde dataset:

```
library(MatchIt)
library(cem)
data(LL)

re74cut <- seq(0, 40000, 5000)
re75cut <- seq(0, max(LL$re75)+1000, by=1000)
agecut <- c(20.5, 25.5, 30.5,35.5,40.5)
my.cutpoints <- list(re75=re75cut, re74=re74cut, age=agecut)

matchit.match <- matchit(treated ~ age + education + black + married + nodegree + 
                           re74 + re75 + hispanic + u74 + u75,
                         data = LL,
                         method = "cem",
                         cutpoints = my.cutpoints)

matchit.data <- match.data(matchit.match)

matchit.imb <- imbalance(group=matchit.data$treated,
                         data=matchit.data,
                         drop=c("treated","re78","distance",
                                "weights","subclass"))

cem.match <- cem(treatment = "treated",
                 data = LL, drop = "re78",
                 cutpoints = my.cutpoints, 
                 eval.imbalance = TRUE)

matchit.imb
cem.match$imbalance
```

Does anybody know what is going on here? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two reasons. First, you must supply the weights from the `matchit` object to `imbalance()`. If you include these, the `(diff)` statistics will be correct, but the L1 statistic will still be wrong.

Second, by using `matchit.data` instead of `LL` in the call to `imbalance()`, the breaks for the L1 statistics are applied using only the matched data instead of the full dataset, which yields a different calculation of the L1 statistic. To correct this, in the call to `imbalance()`, you should supply the original, not matched, dataset, and using the matching weights to provide information on the matches. So, your final call to `imbalance()` should look like the following:

```
imbalance(LL$treated, 
          data=LL, 
          drop=c("treated", "re78"), 
          weights=matchit.match$weights)
```

That will produce the same results as `cem.match$imbalance`.